# Java - Remove all brackets from array using regex

Tags: java, android, arrays, regex

**I have the following array:**

```
[["12","21","31","41"],["empty","22","32","42"],["13","23","33","43"]]
```

**After my regex of:**

```
picset.replaceAll("\\[\\[\"|\"\\]\\]|", "");
```

**Output:**

```
"12","21","31","41"],["empty","22","32","42"],["13","23","33","43"
```

How do I remove the remaining brackets? I should also note I am looping through several arrays with different sizes its not just this specific array.

Comment: Use `picset.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");`

Comment: `.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]+", "")`

Comment: You say you have an Array? but you are treating it like a string. So, which is it? Do you have an Array or a String??

Comment: @Barns it's an array of strings, Though I don't see how that matters with my problem. The comments have solved my issue so thanks to those people.

Comment: It 'matters' because I do not see the purpose in changing an array of strings into a `String` then using `relpaceAll()` just to get another `String` representation of a collection of numbers. You have not said what you intended to do with the new `String` once you get it, but somehow I doubt that you are finished with the result as it is. Besides that (no offense to Istvan) but the accepted solution is far from optimal.

Comment: @Barns i'm using it to add each string to the end of a URL to retrieve images though I doubt that helps your understanding.  All the comments solved my issue and it's working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take the logic you are forcing try adding another line of code.

```
picset.replaceAll("\\[\\[\"|\"\\]\\]|", "");
picset.replaceAll("\"\\],\\[\"", "\",\"");
```